# Failed to resolve: com.android and gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, kotlin

when I append the following lines inside the dependencies section

```
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
```

I got two errors:

> Failed to resolve: com.android ;
>
> Gradle project sync failed.Basic functionality(eg editing,debugging) will not work properly.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.raywenderlich.isell"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  // Kotlin
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlinVersion"
  // AppCompat
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
  // Design Support Library
  implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
  // CardView
  implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
}
```

How to solve these problems?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Replace With Below code and provide appropriate version for  each **kotlinVersion ,supportLibraryVersion**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    ext {
        kotlinVersion = ""
        supportLibraryVersion = ""
    }

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.raywenderlich.isell"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  // Kotlin
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlinVersion"
  // AppCompat
  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
  // Design Support Library
  implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
  // CardView
  implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
}
```

Hope this will help you.